Am I able to see a live count on users actively on my Orbot relay?
I'm unable to find any information on this online. I could find in the app how many connections I've had in the past. I could also see in the log when active connections are made.
However, I'm unable to see a live count for currently connected users on my Orbot relay. Is this possible?

the app name is nyx - it's like top utility for Tor instance. Connect it to any Tor node - including the Orbot one - and see the live stats
